# Join string to array with Regex

Tags: arrays, ruby

Given this string:

```
"ManagerID='26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902' OR ManagerID='c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327'"
```

How can I transform it to this array:

```
["26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902", "c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327"]
```

Basically pulling out the `OR` and joining it. I can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: `str.scan(/(?<=ManagerID=').*?(?=')/)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "ManagerID='26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902' OR ManagerID='c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327'"

string.split(" OR ").map{ |x| x.gsub(/(^ManagerID='|'$)/, "") }
```

Answer (score 0):

ruby noob here, any way

```
 "ManagerID='26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902' OR
 ManagerID='c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327'".gsub(" OR ",'')
```

would produce =>`"ManagerID='26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902' ManagerID='c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327'"`

then split it by `ManagerID=`

```
    "ManagerID='26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902'
 ManagerID='c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327'".split("ManagerID=")
```

would produce => `['26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902', '26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902']`

then simply join them by coma

`['26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902', '26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902'].join(',')`

this should give you the expected result, basically you can chain these operations into one statement, if my knowledge is correct, below code would give you the result.

```
 "ManagerID='26a20e0e-23ba-4133-8bf4-e56f13115902' OR ManagerID='c86eede4-fdb4-45a8-88cf-4041c9d7a327'".gsub(" OR ",'').split("ManagerID=").join(',')
```